# No funciona la ejecución de la sentencia SQL y me devuelve error (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, mvc

Estoy haciendo una sentencia INSERT INTO y hago el bindParam correspondiente, luego meto en un if el execute pero me responde es con el else.

```
public function mostrarImagenController($datos){

list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($datos["imagenTemporal"]);

if($ancho < 1920 || $alto < 1080){
    echo 0;
}else{
    $fecha = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");

    $ruta = "../../views/images/carrusel/slide".$fecha.".jpg";

    $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($datos["imagenTemporal"]);

    imagejpeg($origen, $ruta);

    $respuesta = GestorSlideModel::subirImagenSlideModel($ruta, "slide");

    echo $respuesta;
   }
}
```

---

```
public function subirImagenSlideModel($datos, $tabla){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(ruta) VALUES (:ruta)");

    $stmt -> bindParam(":ruta", $datos, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt->execute()){

        return "ok";
    }

    else{

        return "error";
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se porque siempre me arroja error, luego de ejecutar el execute después de preparar la sentencia SQL y todo

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa es la db, por sise necesita para revisar

Comment: No se yo si eso de `$tabla(ruta)` le va a gustar.

Comment: Mira qué te dice la dase de datos: (1) Almacena la conexión con `$conn = Conexion::conectar()`. (2) Luego `$stmt = $conn->prepare(...)`. (3) En el `else`, añade `var_dump($conn->errorInfo());`.

Comment: ¿La tabla sobre la que haces el insert tiene más campos? Asegurate que no haya alguno que sea obligatorio (no puede contener valores nulos) aparte del campo "ruta"

Comment: Si la tabla tiene mas campos el id y otras cosas pero no les he puesto nada de null

Comment: Jotaelesalinas, cuando pongo el error info me arrija esto respuesta array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

espero que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda.

Probá hacer un "**$stmt->error**" en el "else", ya que el error viene del SQL.

Otra prueba que podés hacer es probar la consulta SQL desde phpMyAdmin y ver si se ejecuta correctamente o también tira error, y ver cuál es el error.

Saludos.

Comment: efectivamente revise en el phpmyadmin y lo solucione, puse que los otros valores puedan ser null